# the new position of the players playing in the background and the audioplayer are different when played at the same time

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, playback, just-audio, spleeter

```
seek(
double newValue,
 ) async {
audioPlayer.positionStream.listen((event) {
  if (event == _audioDuration) {
    print(newValue);
    _saveValue = 0;
    notifyListeners();
    stopAll2();
    recordBool(false);

    // Update the icon  to play button
  } else {
    if (audioPlayer.playing) {
      // print('false');

      recordBool(true);
    }
  }
});

if (_startPlaybackTime == 0.0) {
  _startPlaybackTime = audioPlayer.duration!.inMilliseconds.toDouble();
  _startDuration = audioPlayer.duration!;

  _vocalDuration = vocalPlayer.duration!;
  _bassDuration = bassPlayer.duration!;
  _pianoDuration = pianoPlayer.duration!;
  _drumDuration = drumsPlayer.duration!;
  _otherDuration = otherPlayer.duration ?? const Duration();

  notifyListeners();
}
// Duration background = Duration(milliseconds: newValue.round());
   await Future.wait([
  _audioPlayer.load(), // Load the audio player before seeking
 vocalPlayer.load(),
 bassPlayer.load(),
   pianoPlayer.load(),
  otherPlayer.load(),
  drumsPlayer.load(),
  ]);
await vocalPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds: newValue.round()));
await bassPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds: newValue.round()));
await pianoPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds: newValue.round()));
await otherPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds: newValue.round()));
await drumsPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds: newValue.round()));



double dura = _vocalDuration.inMilliseconds.toDouble() - newValue;
double recordedAudioStartOffset =
    newValue / _vocalDuration.inMilliseconds.toDouble();

double adjustedStartClipTime =
    recordedAudioStartOffset * _startPlaybackTime;


Duration start = Duration(milliseconds: adjustedStartClipTime.toInt());
print('recordedAudioStartOffset: $recordedAudioStartOffset');
print('star ${audioDuration.inMilliseconds.toDouble()}');
print('new value ${_songDuration.inMilliseconds.toDouble()}');
print('startPlay $start');
try {
  await _audioPlayer
   .setClip(start:start)
      .whenComplete(() async {
    _isClipSet = true;
    notifyListeners();
    print('Acomp');

  
  });
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print(e);
}

notifyListeners();
```

}

**This is my code , the process starts when i'm recording an audio and the vocalPlayer, bassPlayer, drumPlayer, PianoPlayer, OtherPlayer play simultaneously and when i change the position of all  using the slider widget and start singing (this is like a karaoke app) and then stop and i click the play button this seek method comes into effect with the newvalue containing the seeked position , the audioplayer doesn't start precisely from where the 5 players(vocalPlayer, bassPlayer, drumPlayer, pianoPlayer, OtherPlayer ) were seeked **